# calculated date & time column, sharepoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint-2007

With the following formula in my calculated column which formats the date & time column:

```
=TEXT(DatePublished,"d/m/yyyy")
```

How may i make sure the other dates are disabled when users create a custom list item, ie. users have actually no option to select any other dates?

Or maybe disable the calendar when they click on the calendar icon?

A workaround or am i missing out a lot?

Answer (score 0):

oh my, sorry. I missed out something big, could have used the already available 'Created' field. Then create another calculated column 'DatePublished' with formula:

```
=TEXT(Created,"dd/m/yyyy")
```